# How to handle date picker in Cypress

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, cypress

How to select a past date in the DOB field? What Javascript function can I use in Cypress automation?

It is not a free text field, only can select from the date picker. Here is the screenshot and the HTML

[image: DOB date picker]

```
<input _ngcontent-kgi-c484="" id="dob" formcontrolname="dob" readonly=""
  bsdatepicker="" placeholder="Optional" class="form-control 
  plore-form-control ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty" ng-reflect-name="dob" 
  ng-reflect-bs-config="[object Object]" 
  ng-reflect-max-date="Fri Apr 16 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1">
```

I tried this function but it didn't work

```
cy.get('#dob').invoke('val').then((text) => {
   expect('08/05/1999').to.equal(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did was add a custom command (we have various datepickers throughout our system, each having a slightly different selector).

```
Cypress.Commands.add("setDateInput", (selector, value) => {
    // wait for the flatpickr instance to be applied before setting the date
    // 'flatpickr-input' class is added on initiation
    cy.get(`${selector}.flatpickr-input`).then($el => {
        $el.get(0)._flatpickr.setDate(value, true)
    })
});
```

Here, you can pass in a changing selector and then the DD/MM/YYYY format as parameters. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Hello, is it the full code of your date pickers? I want to use it but I can't be sure that how the code is sure that picked true date. Are there any other methods which are they supporting that cypress command? If not please can you explain this a little bit better i.e. with one basic example etc.

Answer (score 2):

The control is a bunch of buttons, you can click them in Cypress, e.g

```
cy.get('button').contains('8').click();  // select the 8th day
```

The chevrons (left and right) you'll need to click a few times,

```
cy.get('button.uib-left').click().click().click().click()  // keep going for MM/YY
```

<s>You can click on that middle part, but I can't figure that one out exactly.</s>

Ok, I figured it out, click "April 2021" once to choose the month

```
cy.get('button').contains('April 2021').click();  
// now select the month
cy.get('button').contains('May').click()
```

OR click the "April 2021" then "2021" to select the year

```
cy.get('button').contains('April 2021').click();
cy.get('button').contains('2021').click();  
cy.get('button.uib-left').click().click()    // get decade with 1999
// now select the year
cy.get('button').contains('1999').click()
```

But you get the idea, interact the way a user does.